# error C2079: 'X::x' uses undefined struct 'T'

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

The following example is in error because `X` uses undefined `struct T`

```
struct T;

struct X {

    X() { }

    T x;
};

struct T
{
    T() { w = new X(); }

    X *w;

};

int main() { }
```

One way I can resolve this is by using a pointer member in `struct X` instead of complete type as `T *x`. Is there any tricky way to resolve this without changing any type in code?

Comment: Maybe define T first, as X seems to only use a pointer to X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swap them and outline the constructor of `T`. That way, `T` and `X` are both complete where needed.

```
struct X;

struct T
{
    T();

    X *w;

};

struct X {

    X() { }

    T x;
};

T::T() { w = new X(); }

int main() { }
```